# Bypassing parts of my code based on user input, obj-C if else if or #if #elif?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

In my game, I'm trying to switch from versus AI to versus human opponent within a single game viewcontroller according to user input from a previous menu screen. Should I control the switch with simple objective-C if statements or is it possible to use #if #elif #endif?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if` is for deciding things when your program is running.

`#if` is for deciding things when your program is compiled.

If you want to support both paths in the same build of the program, you should be using `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `#if` is interpreted at compile time (and anything excluded at compile time simply isn't in your program), and you want to make the change at run time, your only reasonable choice is 'simple Objective-C `if` statements'.